# Transfering variable from one page to antother page containing HTML area same component in people code

Tags: peoplesoft

I amd new in people code , creating one application  in which we need to transfer variable from one peoplecode page to antother page containing HTML area. When i am trying to do the same i am getting blank page.

Comment: Please show us your peoplecode and explain what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transfer variable values from one peoplecode event (e.g. page1.activate) to another (e.g. page2.activate).

- First and better solution: Assign your html area object to a component record field and you can access its value within context of your component.
- Another solution: Declare a variable at component level

Comment: Hi Franks  thanks for above comment my requirement is i am  reading on pdf file signdata and passing in one method of java class to get hash data of pdf .After that  i am taking that hash data and put it one variable inside HTML area in which we are calling java script function  deployjava.js to load jre on that HTML area  but that is not happining.       We are able to  load JRE properly if   using only html area without peoplesoft code in separate page

Comment: Please add your source code to your question. In addition, describe your component, page and field definitions concerned by this workflow. Otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Hi Franks Please suggest  is there is any way to access people code variable from  static HTML area (defined as constant ) not from dynamic HTML area.(defined as field ).